# Docusign Rest api : signer authentication methods and how they would fit into request body JSON

Tags: json, docusignapi

I want to add phone verification as well as SMS verification for client authentication. I was able to use access code verification but I am having issues while using phone verification. I am using below request body string but it is not working. Can anyone guide me what is the issue?

```
{ 
   status: "sent", 
   emailSubject: "SECURE: Request a signature via email example", 
   documents: 
   { 
      { 
         documentId: "1", 
         name:"docName",  
         documentBase64: "docNumber" 
       } 
    }, 
    recipients: 
       { 
          signers: 
             { 
                { 
                   name: "signerName", 
                   email: "signerEmail", 
                   recipientId: "1", 
                   accessCode: "1231231230", 
                   phoneAuthentication: 
                      { 
                         recipMayProvideNumber: "704XXXXXXX",
                         validateRecipProvidedNumber: "704XXXXXXX",
                         recordVoicePrint: "1231231231",
                         senderProvidedNumbers: [ "902XXXXXXX" ] 
                      }, 
                   tabs: 
                      { 
                         signHereTabs: 
                            { 
                               { 
                                  xPosition: "128", 
                                  yPosition: "550", 
                                  documentId: "1", 
                                  pageNumber: "1" 
                                } 
                            } 
                      } 
                   } 
                } 
             } 
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The request you provide above is for Phone Authentication (which does a voice phone call), not SMS.

For SMS use something like this in your recipient:

```
"smsAuthentication":{
    "senderProvidedNumbers":[
        "{{recipient1MobilePhone}}"
    ]
}
```

Note:  phone authentication (not SMS) has some restrictions on the phone number due to language constraints and to prevent unintended non-US dialling.  If you require extra-US phone authentication please contact your DocuSign Account Manager.